# Separating List Using a delimiter in Python

Tags: python, csv, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

UPDATED(I'm sorry, it's my first question)

I'm an intern and really new into coding.
In my job, I have to read a file from Azure storage and then insert this data into a database.
To do this, I'm using `get_file_to_text().content` and storing its value in a variable `file` as follows:

`file = file_service.get_file_to_text('teste','','Retorno.csv').content`

and then, I'm using `.splitlines()` like this:

`formFile.append(file.splitlines())`

**I expected a result like this(each line of my file being a sublist):**

`[['2017-08-01', 'Zabbix server Sura', 'system.cpu.load[percpu,avg5]', '0.2900', '0.05217361111111111111', '0.1'], ['2017-08-01', 'Zabbix server Sura', 'system.cpu.util[,iowait]' ... ]`

But I've got this(One big sublist with all the lines inside):

`[['2017-08-01;Zabbix server Sura;system.cpu.load[percpu,avg5];0.2900;0.05217361111111111111;0.1', '2017-08-01;Zabbix server Sura;system.cpu.util[,iowait]; ... ']]`

I also tried a `.split(';')`:

`file2 = file.split(';')`

But it returns me a list with the values only:

`['2017-08-01', 'Zabbix server Sura', 'system.cpu.load[percpu,avg5]', '0.2900', '0.05217361111111111111', '0.1\n2017-08-01', 'Zabbix server Sura', 'system.cpu.util[,iowait]', ...]`

What can I do toget the result I expect?

Thanks!

UPDATE (RESOLVED):
I did this an it worked fine.

```
data = []
azurestorage_text = file_service.get_file_to_text('teste', '', 
'Retorno.csv').content
with StringIO(azurestorage_text) as file_obj:
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter=';')
    header = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        data.append(line)
```

Comment: what you looking for is `.split()` method of string obj

Comment: You've given a lot of details not relevant to your core issue. [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46201295/edit) it to be more focused will help potential answerers.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Edited, trying to follow your instruction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.splitlines()` will split the lines in the text input, returning a list of *whole lines*. In order to parse that into fields (bits between semicolons) you would need to then `.split(';')` each line, e.g.

```
lines = text.splitlines()
rows = []
for line in lines:
    row.append(line.split(';'))
```

However if you want to split semicolon-separated text like this you should be using `csv.reader` to parse the data. It is more robust at handling CSV formats, including for example "quoted text". Splitting on semicolons will break if any of the fields in the data have semicolons within them, e.g. "semicolons in quoted; text".

`csv.reader` requires a file-like object to operate on, rather than a string. To pass in a string, you can use `StringIO` to create a file-like interface to it:

For Python2:

```
from StringIO import cStringIO as StringIO
import csv

text = file_service.get_file_to_text('teste','','Retorno.csv').content
file_obj = StringIO(text)
reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter=';')

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

For Python3:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

file_obj = StringIO(text)


text = file_service.get_file_to_text('teste','','Retorno.csv').content
file_obj = StringIO(text)
reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter=';')

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Each `row` will contain a single line from your file, split into fields on the semicolons (specified by `delimiter`).

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it and worked! Updated the question with the code block